# How can I detect the animationend event on a pseudo element?

Tags: javascript, css

I know how to detect an `animationend` event with a regular DOM element, but how do you do it with a pseudo-element?

I know the event to look for is `animationend`, but how do I attach the pseudo-element with a handler using that event?

I have tried the following, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
document.querySelector("#someSelector:after").addEventListener("animationend",...,false)
```

How can I do this in vanilla JavaScript?

Answer (score 3):

`:after` pseudo-elements can't be selected as though they're part of the DOM, because, in short, they're not part of the DOM. That being said, it is possible to get the event triggers you'd expect, as they're fired on the "parent" of the `:after`.

For example, if you have your `:after` on a DOM element with `id` of `'containybox'`, then you can grab that DOM element and trigger on its `animationend`. The event will then fire when the `:after`'s animation ends.

```
var containerBox = document.getElementById('containybox');    

containerBox.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
  console.log("Animation ended!");
});
```

**Full working snippet:**

```js
var containerBox = document.getElementById('containybox');

containerBox.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
  console.log("Animation ended!");
});

containerBox.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
  console.log("Transition ended!");
});
```

```css
#containybox {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fadebc;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
#containybox:after {
  content: "Standard aftermibob.";
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 120px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #bcdefa;
  animation: animatedBackground 1000ms linear;
}
#containybox:hover:after {
  background: #bcfade;
  transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}
@keyframes animatedBackground {
  from {
    background-color: #000000;
  }
  to {
    background-color: #bcdefa;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="containybox">
  Just a standard containybox.
</div>
```

Comment: You can even distinguish what exactly had been animated from `AnimationEvent.pseudoElement` property, which is either empty string or "::after" / "::before". AnimationEvent object is passed to your event listener as the first parameter.

Comment: Oops, `pseudoElement` property is missing in `AnimationEvent` in Chrome (bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=437132 ). In `TranstitionEvent` it is present both in Chrome and Firefox.